# Azure Devops Parameter condition

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  type: string
  default: dev

- name: region
  type: string
  default: ${{ if or(eq(parameters.environment, 'dev'), eq(parameters.environment, 'tst')) }}central${{ else }}${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'both') }}central, east${{ else }}east${{ endif }}${{ endif }}
```

I am putting condition as if the parameter environment is dev or test  then the parameter region will be central and for other environments, the region will be central, east, both

**But at the same time I am getting error as directive are not supported for the expression that are embedded**

Comment: Is that the actual syntax you're using, including linebreaks and everything else? That doesn't look like it's valid. There's no `${{ endif }}`, for starters. Begin by reviewing the documentation on compile-time expressions. Beyond that, I don't think you can use compile-time expressions in parameters at all.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me out but its not work although as in parameter condition is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can run an expression in a parameter. To achieve the desired behavior I think you'd rather run your expression to set a variable value based on the condition.

So it would be:

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  type: string
  default: dev

variables:
  ${{ if or(eq(parameters.environment, 'dev'), eq(parameters.environment, 'tst')) }}:
    region: 'central'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'both') }} :
    region: 'central, east'
  ${{ else }} :
    region: 'east'
```

I have not tested this; however, this approach should work. You'd reference your region then as `${{ variables.region}}` and can pass it along to future inputs/templates.

Here's a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823004/how-can-i-use-if-else-in-variables-of-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-with-variable-g) as well that provides an example.

Comment: Here is the link for my pipeline :- https://github.com/svikash4/calculator/blob/master/config-service-data-load