# Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML: /azure-pipelines.yml: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, yaml, azure-pipelines

```
variables:
   ${{ if eq(environment, 'dev') }}:
     - group: 'newgroupa'
${{ else }}:
     - group: 'newgroupb'
```

The above lines in yml gives me object not set to reference error.

I even tried by adding -
example

```
  variables:
      - ${{ if eq(environment, 'dev') }}:
         - group: 'newgroupa'
      - ${{ else }}:
         - group: 'newgroupb'
```

and that gave me another error Unexpected value 'group'. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: whats with the indents?

Comment: i think it should be like in your first example, just with fixed indents

Answer (score 0):

example from a random blog post:

```
variables:
  - name: teamName
    ${{ if eq( parameters['environment'], 'developer') }}:
      value: "alpha"
    ${{ if eq( parameters['environment'], 'preproduction' ) }}:
      value: "beta"
    ${{ if notIn( parameters['environment'], 'developer', 'preproduction') }}:
      value: "charlie"
```

or from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57532526/6067741

```
  ${{ if eq( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master' ) }}: 
    buildVersion: ${{ variables['mavenVersion'] }}
  ${{ if ne( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master' ) }}: 
    buildVersion: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}
```