# Can't Conditionally Define Azure DevOps Pipeline Variable

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to use the Environment.Name / ENVIRONMENT_NAME [Deployment job variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deployment-job-variables-devops-services) in an Azure Devops Pipeline YAML while defining a variable. However, I cannot seem to get a value to resolve. I have tried other simpler variables that are always '1', just to make sure I didn't make a mistake with my comparison.

I've tried other syntax as well, such as 'Environment.Name', variables.Environment.Name, etc... Without luck. However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63175338/21319935) question, Environment.Name should have worked. The conditions work when the variable is defined right above in the same section, however I need to use the system/Azure defined version as it provides the correct environment name.

```
variables:
- name: Suffix
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'DEV' ) }}:
    value: '003'
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'TEST' ) }}:
    value: '003'
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'STAGE' ) }}:
    value: '001'
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'PROD' ) }}:
    value: '001'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your job actually a deployment job? i.e. instead of `- job:`, it's `- deployment:`.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment job variables will be resolved only at job execution time. The syntax `${{}}` is for compile time, so the value of `Suffix` is empty in your case.

As a workaround, you can use [output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts). See the sample shown below.

```
jobs:
- deployment: testdeployment   
  displayName: deploymentjob1  
  environment: PROD  
  strategy:
    runOnce:   
      deploy:
        steps: 
        - script: |
            if [ "$(Environment.Name)" == "DEV" ] || [ "$(Environment.Name)" == "TEST" ]; then
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Suffix;isOutput=true]003"
            elif [ "$(Environment.Name)" == "STAGE" ] || [ "$(Environment.Name)" == "PROD" ]; then
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Suffix;isOutput=true]001"
            fi
          name: setvarStep
        - script: echo $(setvarStep.Suffix)
```

When the environment is `PROD`, the value of `Suffix` is 001.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using parameters instead of variables. Because variables are not available during compile time (when you use `${{}}`). As example:

```
parameters:
- name: env_param
  displayName: env_param
  type: string  
  default: DEV
  values:
  - DEV
  - TEST
  - STAGE
  - PROD

variables:
- name: Suffix_var
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'DEV' ) }}:
    value: '003'
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'TEST' ) }}:
    value: '003'
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'STAGE' ) }}:
    value: '001'
  ${{ if eq( variables['ENVIRONMENT_NAME'], 'PROD' ) }}:
    value: '001'
- name: Suffix_param
  ${{ if eq( parameters.env_param, 'DEV' ) }}:
    value: '003'
  ${{ if eq( parameters.env_param, 'TEST' ) }}:
    value: '003'
  ${{ if eq( parameters.env_param, 'STAGE' ) }}:
    value: '001'
  ${{ if eq( parameters.env_param, 'PROD' ) }}:
    value: '001'

steps:

- bash: echo "$(Suffix_var)"
  name: Suffix_var

- bash: echo "$(ENVIRONMENT_NAME)"
  name: var_value

- bash: echo "$(Suffix_param)"
  name: param
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]